# How to resolve "symbol lookup error" on .NET Core on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

Using Visual Studio, created .NET Core 3.1 C# DLL for use on Linux.
Upon Linux "dotnet MyApplication.dll", trigger System.DllNotFoundException, but the problem appears to be six "symbol lookup errors":

```
3139: /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.60: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: u_strlen (fatal)
3139: /usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.11/System.Globalization.Native.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: GlobalizationNative_CompareStringW (fatal)
3139: /usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.11/System.Globalization.Native.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: GlobalizationNative_GetDefaultLocaleNameW (fatal)
3139: /usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.11/System.Globalization.Native.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: GlobalizationNative_GetLocaleNameW (fatal)
3139: /usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.11/System.Globalization.Native.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: GlobalizationNative_GetLocaleInfoStringW (fatal)
3139: /usr/lib64/libplmwdm-c.so: error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: protobuf_c_empty_string (fatal)
```

How can I resolve these "symbol lookup errors"?
Four are .NET Core related.

- u_strlen (Unicode strlen) is libicuuc.so.60 related, but libicuuc.so.60 is resolved and loaded successfully.
- protobuf_c_empty string is related to one of more protobuf RPMs that I installed, all ".so" files present in the local directory.
- None of the six are directly referenced by my trivial application, but I do reference one method in libplmwtss-c.so, a customer library, and unquestionably libplmwtss-c.so triggers all the other references.
- LIB_DEBUG=all indicates libplmwtss-c.so is resolved and loaded without problem, numerous other ".so" files are resolved and loaded without problem, but these six problem references remain.

Comment: This is RHEL 8, right? Could you share more information about how you created the DLL using Visual Studio? Can you reproduce the issue if you use the command line `dotnet publish` command? Can you reproduce any of the issues if you use a simple "hello-world" style program and try and run that? Can you share the output of running `ldd` on each of the `.so` files that produce the symbol error?

Comment: Not quite RHEL 8 but Centos8. Using VS2019, click File, New Project, C# Console Application, Target Framework .NET Core 3.1. Have Centos8 running under VirtualBox. A trivial "Hello World" works, i.e., "dotnet HelloWorld.dll" indeed prints out "hello world". But then I added a DllImport of "libplmwtss-c" with a method in that dot-so, and calling that method causes the fault. I'm afraid the LD_DEBUG=all output is 7MB. Here is a OneDrive link https://1drv.ms/t/s!ArFHTzWIP6DTgxUn48uWyvv2BNlB?e=twzgqa

Comment: Thanks. Is `libplmwdm-c.so` accessible publicly? Any way I can get a copy of that? Does a `yum install protobuf-devel` help?

Comment: That, I'm afraid, is customer confidential. Using "readelf -a", I've verified that "u_strlen" is in lilbicuuc.so, which the LD_DEBUG=all clearly indicates is found and loaded without problem. I suspect the same is the case for the other five unresolved symbols. If "u_strlen" is in libicuuc.so, and libicuuc.so is loaded without problem, why is loaded complaining that "u_strlen" is unresolved?

Comment: I would suggest focusing on the error that's mentioned in the DllNotFoundException. That's just libplmwtss-c.so, right? The rest may be red herrings. Can you share the output of `ldd libplmwtss-c.so`?

Comment: Apologies for the formatting; I'm learning mini-Markdown

Comment: Here it is:  <br/>
 linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffff864000)  <br/>
 libplmwdm.so (0x00007fd1250cd000)  <br/>
 libplmwtim.so (0x00007fd124eca000)  <br/>
 libplmwtsm.so (0x00007fd124b47000)  <br/>
 libplmwdm-c.so (0x00007fd12491a000)  <br/>
 libc.so.6 (0x00007fd124557000)  <br/>
 libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd1241c2000)  <br/>
 libm.so.6 (0x00007fd123e40000)  <br/>
 libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd123c28000)  <br/>
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd1255b3000)  <br/>

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same errors, along with other ones. I solved them by installing all the missing libraries. Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-bionic AS base

ENV TZ=Europe/Bucharest
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys Your_Missing_Key_1
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys Your_Missing_Key_2

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb http://deb.debian.org/debian sid main'
RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y cups
RUN apt-get install -y libc6-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y libgdiplus
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev libharfbuzz0b libfontconfig1 libfreetype6
RUN apt-get install -y libpango-1.0-0
RUN apt-get install -y libpangocairo-1.0
RUN apt-get update
```

I have also raised a ticket to dotnet/runtime github here:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/52696

Comment: Andrei, thank you, but I am using CentOS8 not Debian [or Ubuntu]. Using CentOS8 "yum', I found "cups" and "gnopg2" were already installed, "libgdiplus" could be installed but all other above items report "unable to find a match". Looking at your GitHub link looks like you had very similar issues, u_strlen, GlobalizationNative_xxx, etc.